# VSCode Go compilation blocked by antivirus

Tags: go, security, antivirus

I am trying to work in VSCode 1.76.0-insiders on Windows 10 and what happens is that GO v1.20 compiler for some reason compile the application to temporary (?) folder - this action blocked by antivirus.

Could you suggest what settings I need to set in `launch.json` to compile into the same folder where source code is ?

Here is output of 'Debug console'

```
Starting: C:\Users\user01\go\bin\dlv.exe dap --only-same-user=false --listen=127.0.0.1:56552 from C:\projects\go.tfs-exporter
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:56552
Build Error: go build -o C:\projects\go.app\__debug_bin.exe -gcflags all=-N -l .
tfs-exporter: go build go.app: open C:\Temp\go-build2738799206\b001\exe\a.out.exe: Access is denied. (exit status 1)
```

you see this **strange** folder: `C:\Temp\go-build2738799206\b001\exe\a.out.exe` ?? This is automatically blocked - no questions asked

here is my `launch.json` file:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "dlvFlags": [
                "--only-same-user=false"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

or any other suggestion on how to configure GO compiler with Antivirus in **corporate** environment ?

Answer (score 1):

https://community.bitdefender.com/en/discussion/84185/false-positive-when-running-go-lang-program-edited-in-visual-studio-code

As advised here https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/bitdefender-detects-output-as-a-virus/22152/8 a "good" solution would be to add the environment variable GOTMPDIR with any path of your choice, where the builds are going to be stored. (Maybe reboot after this)

Then just go to BitDefender Protection -> Antivirus -> Settings -> Manage Exceptions and add your path as an exception.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !
My security team actually "white-listed" the GO language compiler executable to do whatever it wants on computer - and this is solved the problem.